# Is there a way to run an outside executable after a SPECIFIC solution is built in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, build, macros, solution

I had the same question as was asked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177188/is-there-a-way-to-run-an-outside-executable-after-a-solution-is-built-in-visual), i.e. I was looking for a way to run an executable or script after building a solution in Visual Studio.

I tried out the suggested solution of catching the OnBuildDone event with a macro, which (as I understand it) needs to be placed in the EnvironmentEvents section under MyMacros in the Macros IDE.  The problem with this is that it makes the macro global to everything I do in Visual Studio.  In other words, it runs the macro regardless of which solution it is that I am building.  However, I only want it to run for that one solution.

Is there a way to make a macro that catches the OnBuildDone event for a specific solution only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is:

- Define a new, faily empty, project within that solution
- Specify that this new project depends on every other project (so that this new project will be built after all other projects)
- Invoke your executable or script as a build event of this new **project** (instead of, of the solution)