# Alternative to macros in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-macros

I use macros extensively for ViewModel properties in [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) development. I use them even more in [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) to generate Message and DataContract properties.

To my disappointment, the macros I've built aren't going to be usable in Visual Studio 2012.

An example of what I'm talking about, for a VM, I would enter something like this.

```
int id;
string name;
```

Select both lines, run a macro and end up with

```
private int _id;
private string _name;

public int Id
{
   get {return _id;}
   set
   {
      if(_id != value)
      {
        _id = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
      }
}

public string Name
{
   if(_name != value)
   {
      _name = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
   }
}
```

I'm looking for ideas of other solutions deal with losing macros.

Comment: I assume code snippets are going to be the alternative or at least a suggestion.  The issue with code snippets are when I create DataMembers or MessageContractMembers, my macro's automatically calculate and populate the display order of each property.  So I'm hoping there is some alternative to Macros that gives as much flexibility.

Comment: Please see [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: @FrostKris Maybe you should accept Kyralessa's answer

Comment: Wow, that is a cool way to improve productivity and code. Had no clue about it till now. @FrostKris, did you find an alternative way to achieve that in VS2012 by any chance?

Comment: @Frost Kris, I wonder if you found a solution and if you would accept to share your code? I'd be really interested to see/use it.

Comment: I haven't found any alternative to macro's. I just keep Visual Studio 2010, run my macro's there and copy and paste the code into VS 2013 files.  I've created code snippets as well but don't find myself using those as much.

Comment: UPDATE: They're back! (for VS2013 users, at least.) A new extension has been released allowing users to "record most of the commands in Visual Studio including text editing operations." ( details here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b)

Answer (score 65):

The simplest alternative to macros is creating **add-ins**.  I know, I know, I wasn't excited about it either, but it's actually surprisingly easy.  There are three simple parts to it:

1. Create the macro project, stepping through a wizard UI.
2. Write your code.
3. Copy the macro's .addin and .dll files to your Visual Studio `Addins` directory.

Let's take [a simple macro I wrote to show the Start Page after closing a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros/1545872#1545872) and turn it into an add-in.

### Create the macro project

- Run VS 2012 and create a new project.
- Go to Templates > Other Project Types > Extensibility and select **Visual Studio Add-in**.
- Give it a name, such as ShowStartPage.
- Click OK.  This brings up the Add-in Wizard.
- Step through the wizard, choosing:

  - Programming language: we'll use C#
  - Application host: VS 2012 should be selected
  - Name and description for your add-in
  - On the add-in options page, checkmark only the second option ("I would like my Add-in to load when the host application starts")
  - Skip past the About Box stuff for now, and click Finish.

Now you have an add-in project.  Here's what you do with it:

### Write the code

Open the `Connect.cs` file.  (It might already be open.  Some of the "DTE" stuff should look familiar.)

Add this code at class level:

```
SolutionEvents solutionEvents;
```

Add this code to the `OnConnection` method, right after the `_addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;` line:

```
solutionEvents = _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents;

solutionEvents.AfterClosing += () =>
{
    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("View.StartPage");
};
```

Hit the "Run" button to test your code.  A new instance of Visual Studio 2012 starts up, with your add-in loaded.  Now test the add-in and make sure it works.  (Open a solution, then close it; the Start Page should return when you do.)

### Deploy it

Once the add-in works, to use it regularly with Visual Studio 2012, you only need to deploy two files:

- `ShowStartPage.AddIn` (from your main project directory)
- `ShowStartPage.dll` (from your project's build directory; e.g. bin\Debug or bin\Release)

Put those two files in your VS 2012 add-ins directory, probably located here:

`C:\Users\[your user name]\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins`

Then exit and restart Visual Studio, and you should see your add-in working.  You should also see it listed when you go to Tools > Add-in Manager.

While this is a bit more of a nuisance than just opening the macro editor and sticking your macro code in there, it does have the advantage that you can use any language you want, instead of being stuck with the somewhat flaky VB-like editor in past versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: For my own custom commands that want to run want over and over again (especially using keybindings), I checked `Yes, create a 'Tools' menu item...` and added my code within the `Exec()` method between the `if(commandName == ...` and the `handled = true;`.

Comment: Note, that *Add this code at class level* instruction is crucial. If you use a local variable, it will be garbage collected and your handler won't get fired.

Comment: It is actually very easy and extremely flexible, thanks.

Comment: In VS2013 and VS2015RC, I cannot find the Extensibility option under Templates>Other Project Types. It only has Setup and Deployment and Visual Studio Solution. Is there something after install thing that I need to do to get that opiton?

Answer (score 12):

I'll stick to cutting the text into [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and using macros there, then pasting back. It is a shame the feature isn't in Visual Studio 2012 any more...

Answer (score 12):

The [Visual Commander](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) extension (developed by me) is an alternative to macros in Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015. You can even reuse your existing Visual Studio macros code in new VB commands.

Comment: Very useful indeed, since missing macro facility is still a problem in VS 2015. Thanks a lot Sergey!

Comment: This looks like a great tool but I can't seem to get it to record a macro in 2015 (I haven't tried in other vs editions)  I select record macro, then stop, then edit or save but there is nothing inside the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: @atreeonhill It should record text editing commands in VS 2015. Contact me at SergeyVlasov@vlasovstudio.com for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 5):

There is an add-in, [VSScript](http://www.softerg.com/vsscript), for Visual Studio which replaces missing macros functionality. Although it does not use Visual Basic, but the [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) scripting language, you might want to try it out.

There is a recorder, macro code editor window with IntelliSense, and a simple debugger. The add-in also supports earlier versions of Visual Studio, so if you prefer the Lua language rather than Visual Basic, you can use it instead original Visual Studio macros.

Comment: Awesome, glad to see the community picking up where MS fails.

Answer (score 3):

I was very sad to see Macros go too.  You can get close with substitutions using the regular expression search and replace inside of Visual Studio 2012.  In your case:

Find:

```
(.*) (.*);
```

Replace with:

```
private $1 _$2;\npublic $1 $2\n{\n  get {return _$2;}\n  set\n  {\n    if(_$2 = value;\n    RaisePropertyChanged("$2");\n  }\n}\n
```

That will get you everything except capitalization of property names which Macros would be better for.

But one advantage of the regular expression approach is when the input isn't as simple (e.g. database table DDL statements).

Here are a couple of useful links from MSDN:

[Substitutions in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)

[Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks like they are considering bringing them back for a future version of Visual Studio http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2650757-bring-back-macros?tracking_code=797ba9d47520260a9b534e47ba15e8ec

Answer (score 2):

I use Notepad++ with regular expressions like this:

Find:

```
public (.\*) (.)(.*) \\{ get; set; \\}
```

Replace:

```
private \1 \l(\2)\3; \r\n public \1 \2\3 \\{ get \\{ return \l(\2)\3; \\} \r\n set \\{ \l(\2)\3 = value; OnPropertyChanged\(para => this\.\2\3\); \\}\\}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://devexpress.com/coderush

The templates feature does pretty much what you want.

There is a free "Express" version too.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012's lack of macros was getting me down, as I have a few that I use literally all the time to insert standard little bits of text with a single keypress. So I wrote a very simple scripts extensibility package, [VSScripts](https://github.com/tom-seddon/VSScripts), which allows manipulation of the current selection from a command-line program.

This doesn't claim to be some all-encompassing full replacement for the old macro system, and it doesn't provide keyboard macros, but it does make it possible to recreate many types of text manipulation macro.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to keep my macro functionality...

1. Download and install the Visual Studio 2012 SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668) (it contains the "Visual Studio Package" template)
2. New project -> Installed.Templates.Visual C#.Extensibility.Visual Studio Package

   Wizard page 1 of 7

   ```
   language = C#
   gen new key is fine, or use another if you have one
   ```

   wizard page 3 of 7

   ```
   check "menu command"
   ```

   Wizard page 7 of 7

   ```
   uncheck both integration and unit test project options
   ```

   Click finish
3. In the .cs file:

   ```
   using EnvDTE;
   using EnvDTE80;

   ...
   private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MenuCommand cmd = sender as MenuCommand;

       // This should start to look like familiar macro code...
       EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2;
       TextSelection selection = (TextSelection)dte2.ActiveDocument.Selection;

       dte2.UndoContext.Open("macro command replacement");
       selection.Text = "inserted from macro replacement";
       selection.NewLine(1);
       dte2.UndoContext.Close();
       ...
   ```
4. Run the project. A new Visual Studio instance will start with the package loaded.
5. Find your command as the first entry at the top of the Tools menu. Click it to see if it works.
6. To install for real, go to your bin\debug(/release) directory and double-click on the .vsix file
7. It should be installed for the next time you run
8. Go to menu *Tools* -> *Options...* -> environment.keyboard and map a keystroke to your tool

   ```
   Mapping theme : Visual C# 2005
   Command       : Tool.yourFunctionName (functions defined in the .vsct file)
   ```

If you want more than one command, you will need to add menu id's in the PkgCmdID.cs, Guids in the Guids.cs, layouts in the .vsct and a function in the *package.cs (and button(MenuCommand) in the Initialize function) for each one. It can all be done in the same project.

I used this project to create several new 'tools' with my old macro code, then mapped my keys to them. It's a lot more work (and headaches) up front, but doesn't have the lag time that macros had.

There is probably a way to do this without having it take up tool menus. I started looking at this last night and finally got it to work, so I'm done with it for now (at least until Microsoft decides to drop this too).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like this one - the [Visual Commander](http://componentwanted.com/visual-commander-professional-includes-1-year-of-software-updates-and-technical-support/) extension lets you automate repetitive tasks in Visual Studio.