# Collapse all xml comments in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, macros, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions, xml-comments

I have recently been given an existing project to work with that is very comment heavy, especially in terms of XML comments. In many cases the methods are short and simple and the XML comments take up more than half of the lines in the file. As much as I'd like to blow them all away with a quick find/replace, I'm not in a position to do so.

Is there a command, extension, macro, anything that will collapse all XML comment blocks in a couple of clicks/keystrokes? My Googling has only yielded solutions for older versions of VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog post](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/30), the macro provides two functionalities - one is **collapse all XML comments**, the other one is **toggle all XML comments**.

The blog post mentioned that the macro should work for Visual Studio 2005 and above so I suppose it will work in VS 2012 too. I am using VS 2010 and it is working great for me even after I [hook the macro up with keyboard shortcuts](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/8). I am glad that I found the blog post link in [one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328640/2809828) in another stack overflow question =)

Comment: "I suppose it will work in VS 2012 too". No it doesn't, since the macro feature is [removed from VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013) :-(

Comment: @Steven Yea, I realised that sometime after I answer this question. You can check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012) especially the [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012/12394986#12394986) and the [fourth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012/18888317#18888317) answers. Both of them are not exactly the macro in VS2010 but with some work should be able to perform the same trick.