# Running external command on file save in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm reading this article on integrating cppcheck into VS: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/472065/Poor-Man-s-Visual-Studio-Cppcheck-Integration

I want running the check upon saving file, which is covered in the article. But, the article refers to Macros IDE, which, apparently, was taken out of VS2012. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked into something like what this answer suggests http://stackoverflow.com/a/12394986/479512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Mark Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986356/46635), I installed and used [Visual Commander](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) to do something similar. This is my extension, that runs the first external tool when files in my project ("my-project") are saved:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE_, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        DTE = DTE_;
        events = DTE.Events;
        documentEvents = events.DocumentEvents;
        documentEvents.DocumentSaved += OnDocumentSaved;        
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        documentEvents.DocumentSaved -= OnDocumentSaved;
    }

    private void OnDocumentSaved(EnvDTE.Document doc)
    {
        if(doc.Path.ToLower().Contains("my-project")) DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand1");
    }

    private EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.DocumentEvents documentEvents;
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty much like what I eventually did.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a free Tool available called [`Visual Commander`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) available in the Visual Studio Gallery, more information [here](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/).

from first link:

> Automate repetitive tasks in Visual Studio IDE. **Reuse your existing Visual Studio macros** or create new commands and extensions in C# or VB.
>
> A Visual Commander command is a class written in C# or VB implementing the Run method. It has full access to the Visual Studio automation model and .NET framework. Code of an existing Visual Studio macro from previous versions of Visual Studio can be just pasted in the Run subroutine of a new VB command.

Answer (score 1):

You could almost certainly write a visual studio extension to do something along these lines. I wrote an extension [VSFileNav](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af) which hooks up to project events to listen for items being removed/added etc. I imagine a slightly different event on a project (or possibly even some document window) would allow you to do such a thing.

[DocumentEventClass.DocumentSaved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documenteventsclass.documentsaved%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
[DTE.ActiveDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._dte.activedocument.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) can do what you want since version 1.15.