# Insert current date time in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know that [there is a way for us to insert current date time in `VS 2010`](http://thecurlybraces.com/macro-to-insert-date-time-in-visual-studio-2010/) using Macros, but `VS 2012` dropped support for Macros.

How would you go about achieving this in VS2012?

Comment: At a guess, ReSharper might support this in their code snippets.

Comment: There's some good information on alternatives in this post: [Alternative to Macros in Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012)